# Create font with connecting letters

Tags: fonts, ligatures

Some letters in devangiri may appear on top of each other, or maybe next to each other with both of them halved. Like this: खा. This is actually a combination of 2 letters,ख and ी. I'm working with fontstruct, and I was wondering how I could replicate this myself.

Comment: It has something to do with the x-y positioning on the glyphs. You need to set the `matra` to some negative x-position in order to patch it with the previous character.

Comment: Or it's perhaps made as *ligatures* in sophisticated fonts. Not sure fontstruct supports ligatures.

Comment: Is there a free font builder that _does_ support ligatures?

Comment: [FontForge](https://fontforge.org/en-US/) does, but it's a much more complex program with a steep learning curve.

Comment: @Wolff im not sure fontforge has a steep learning curve. Its just that if you want everything you need to get a lot of things right. Its not the software that requires to go in with a steep curve its the user who wants to get there too fast.

Comment: @joojaa, haha well then perhaps steep learning curves don't really exist? Joke aside I get what you mean. Font design is a pretty cumbersome endeavor no matter what. I was just comparing to FontStruct which is more of a toy than a tool really.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a glyph for that in fontstruct (see image).  Once you create them, the rendering will be done automatically when you export the font.
[image: Devanagari in Fontstruct]